# Can Google AMP be used with ReactJS application? Is server side rendering mandatory in this case?

Tags: reactjs, amp-html

I have a react app, which uses node at the server side. Can I use AMP in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Implementing AMP for react apps while developing seems to be more easy than AMP-ing already implemented SPAs.

React lets us use AMP components like amp-img or amp-accordion to build our views the same way we use any HTML element, so we can maintain a consistent paradigm with our other React projects.

Implementing AMP pages in AngularJS / React websites are extremely hard compared to drupal and wordpress which have plugins. Single Page Application websites are also very hard to get indexed by Google, stop-gap solutions such as pre-render may work, mileage greatly varies though. If you have a custom website, you will have to invest engineering resources and build it.

Comment: Please accept it as answer if you find this as a solution for the stack overflow community and upvote if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Im using Nextjs (Server Side Rendering) for building an AMP website. You can check here https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-amp

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/amp update link